# Windows server ignoring DNS resolution on private interface

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 server with two interfaces - public internet facing, and private.

The private interface uses our internal DNS servers. This interface has no gateway. Static IP - not DHCP.

I want to disable the public interface, as we use a proxy for outgoing traffic.

Having disabled it, I'm finding DNS resolution failing:

- I cannot ping foo.external.com  - host cannot be found
- However, I can nslookup, notice that it connects to our internal DNS, and successfully resolve foo.external.com
- ipconfig /displaydns DOES show the correct entry.  I'm utterly confused why ping does not simply use this entry.
- If I manually add an entry to local hosts file, for "1.1.1.1 foo", as an experiment, and try ping foo, it fails - cannot resolve host.  Same for foo.external.com, and "foo.external.com.".   Pinging "foo.external.com", or "foo.external.com." also fails.
- If, however, I then re-enable the public interface, it all works.  Including the hosts file. I can ping "foo" (the resolution aspect).  Disable it, and it stops working again.

I've tried all the reboots, ipconfig /flushdns, nbtstat -R stuff.

a) Why is ping (and our application) not able to properly resolve things when the public interface is disabled, despite Windows being able to speak to its DNS server, and cache the result (as shown in ipconfig /displaydns).

b) Why is the hosts file being ignored for the private interface?

Many thanks.

Comment: Naturally, when you disable the external interface the server isn't going to be able to ping external resources because the internal interface has no default gateway. The fact that it can resolve the name via the internal DNS server has no bearing on it's ability to communicate with external hosts. I'm not sure why you're conflating DNS name resolution with routability and reachability. The two don't have any bearing on each other. As for your hosts file entry; did you edit the hosts file from an elevated instance of Notepad (or other text editor)?

Comment: I'm not conflating them. I'm not expecting to be able to ping the external hosts. I am however expecting ping to try and ping the IP it resolves to. It may then fail for routing reasons.  But its failing saying it cannot *resolve* it - when it should be able to.  Yes - host file stuff is working in general. If it wasn't, then there's no way "foo" would have ended up visible in ipconfig /displaydns . "foo" doesn't exist anywhere else.

Comment: Since you can resolve foo.external.com it sounds like DNS resolution is working which is different than trying to ping (ICMP) foo.external.com. Perhaps your proxy settings are not properly configured or preventing your system access to foo.external.com.

Comment: It's not about accessing foo.external.com. The question is why, with one interface disabled (only), and foo.external.com already in the DNS cache (or indeed, in the hosts file), it will not resolve (not connect to).

Comment: @Nik, your question should be updated to be more clear that you're interested only in why resolution fails when the public NIC is disabled, the the correct entry resides in the HOSTS file and local cache. If _ipconfig /displaydns_ shows the correct entry and/or the correct entry is in the HOSTS file everything should work in a default configuration. That said, have settings been implemented to bypass HOSTS lookup and cache? Requiring a DNS lookup every time?

Comment: If there's a setting that exists to bypass HOSTs lookup and cache, and it's specific to an interface, that would explain the behaviour I'm seeing. However, I've never heard of one, and googling around for bypassing hosts file turned up nothing. I am surprised that it appears there is any difference in either of those things, based on the interface in question. I thought they were both higher up the stack - shared.

Comment: Have you verified the DNS server addresses configured on IPv4 (or 6) bound to the internal adapter? 
Is there a reason that you chose to leave the gateway empty for the internal adapter? 
Do you have any DNS suffixes appended to the related DNS search list?

Comment: DNS server - yes. However, with hosts file, should be irrelevant anyway.  Gateway - our provider does it this way - machine does not need to speak to another network.  Suffixes appended - yes - however that is why I was careful to append a "." in my experiments above. Thanks.

Comment: Do other programs also fail to resolve the name? For example, pathping, tracert, telnet, etc.

Comment: Indeed. It's how we noticed the issue actually - our .net windows application - which ultimately calls dns.gethostentry internally - fails to resolve things. Re-enable public interface, and all starts working. Disable and check cache - yip, answer should be available to apps.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with the DNS Client service stopped?

Comment: I might check your Connection order. In `Network Connections`, Go to `Advanced` and `Advanced Settings`. Then make sure your *internal* NIC is on top of the `Connections` section.

Comment: @Nixphoe thanks, but not sure where you mean exactly. There is only one network connection enabled (the private one)

Comment: @JasonAzze I can yes.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search returned [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine) user with the same question:

The user took a Wireshark capture and found that when when trying to ping the host, no DNS query was being performed.

The explanation for this behaviour was:

> I believe that nslookup opens a winsock connection on the DNS port and
>   issues a query, whereas ping uses the DNS Client service. You could
>   try and stop this service and see whether this makes a difference.
>
> Some commands that will reinitialize various network states :
>
> Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults : `netsh winsock reset catalog`
>   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults : `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
>   Flush DNS resolver cache : `ipconfig /flushdns`
>   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases : `ipconfig /registerdns`
>   Flush routing table : `route /f` (reboot required)

Comment: Thanks, bit that neither answers my (a) nor (b) questions.

Comment: Have you tried all of the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are your internal DNS Servers on the same subnet as your private interface ? If not, then your server will not know a route to your DNS Servers, and your DNS query will fail.
Add a gateway to your private network settings, or add a static route, so your private NIC knows what it can reach from it.